# Не получается совместить рисунки и кнопки при добавлении их в JFrame либо Jpanel .Java swing

Tags: java, swing, графика

я пытаюсь сделать шашки, но возникла проблема с интерфейсом. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы в окне у меня располагались  доска, кнопки, которые ,допустим, при нажатии  закрашивали какую-либо клетку. Однако почему-то при соединении всех этих элементов ничего не появляется либо что-то одно.

Я сперва добавлял все Jframe,но как я понял нельзя одновременно рисовать и добавлять кнопки. Подумал: нужно использовать Jpanel. В итоге я добавил Jpanel поле и кнопки,но ничего не изменилось.

Также почему-то рисунки не объединяются.

Я хочу делать без layout'ов.

test4 - класс ,где main

```
 import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class test4 extends JPanel {
        public static void main(String arg[]) {
            JFrame frame = getFrame();
            GUI85 gui = new GUI85();
            //gui.setBackground(Color.orange);
            paint pain = new paint();

            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
            JButton button = new JButton();
            button.setBounds(50, 50, 35, 56);
            jPanel.setLayout(null);
            jPanel.add(button);
            frame.add(gui); //поле
            frame.add(jPanel);

            button.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    jPanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
                }
            });

            //frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel);
            //gui.setLocation(50,50);
            //jPanel.add(gui); //поле
            // jPanel.add(gui);//клетку закрашиваем
            //jPanel.add(pain);

            jPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseClicked(e);
                    System.out.println("x=" + e.getX() + "y=" + e.getY());
                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();
                    System.out.println("-------------");
                    int i = (int) ((float) (x - 257)) / 65;
                    int j = (int) ((float) (y - 150)) / 65;
                    System.out.println("i= " + i + " j= " + j);
                    System.out.println("-------------");

                }
            });
        }

        static JFrame getFrame() {
            JFrame jFrame = new JFrame() {
            };
            jFrame.setSize(500, 500);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            return jFrame;
        }
    }
```

GUI85 - класс рисует шашечную доску

````
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
    import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
    import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
    
    public class paint extends JPanel {
    
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            //this.setBackground(Color.orange);
    
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Shape line = new Line2D.Double(3, 3, 303, 303);
            Shape rect = new Rectangle(3, 3, 303, 303);
            Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100);
            Shape roundRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(20, 20, 250, 250, 5, 25);
    
    
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(250 + 65 * 0, 120 + 65 * 0, 65, 65);
    
        }


}```

paint - класс рисует красный квадрат на шашечной доске.
````

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

public class paint extends JPanel {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        //this.setBackground(Color.orange);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Shape line = new Line2D.Double(3, 3, 303, 303);
        Shape rect = new Rectangle(3, 3, 303, 303);
        Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100);
        Shape roundRect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(20, 20, 250, 250, 5, 25);


        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(250 + 65 * 0, 120 + 65 * 0, 65, 65);

    }
```

}```

Answer (score 0):

Почитай здесь: https://java-online.ru/swing-layout.xhtml
Если хочешь привязать кнопки сам нужно прописать:
jFrame.setLayout(null);

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)